# Java pass values into method/function

Tags: java, boolean, arguments, variadic-functions, args

Ok, first of all: hello!

I'll be short.

```
    public static Boolean or (boolean... args){
    // some code to process args and return true or false
return hasArgs & kiekFalse!=args.length ? true : false;
    }
```

Here I have a function called "or" and it has unknown amount of parameters that can be passed into it. I need it, cause I really can't know it.
so
I can use it like that
System.out.println(or(true,true,true,false,true,false));
BUT
what to do when I need to read values for example, for keyboard?
read and convert to Boolean array? does not work, it requires Boolean, not Boolean[]. **Cannot resolve method 'or(java.lang.Boolean[]'**
Pass one by one? nope, I need to pass none or required amount at once.

Any ideas or suggestions?
Ideally, I'd need to figure out how to pass N Booleans from keyboard to or function.. Else I'll just need to rewrite some *(a lot of)* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an overload which takes a `Collection<Boolean>`, converts it to a `boolean[]`, then invokes the method:

```
Boolean or(Collection<Boolean> c) {
  boolean[] b = new boolean[c.size()];
  int i = 0;
  for (Boolean cb : c) {
    b[i++] = cb; // assuming no nulls.
  }
  return or(b);
}
```

(Or you can take a `Boolean[]` parameter; it makes little difference, you just have to use `length` instead of `size()`.)

Then you can just read your booleans in from user input into a List, and invoke this method.

```
List<Boolean> listOfBooleans = new ArrayList<>();
// Read values, add to list
Boolean result = or(listOfBooleans);
```

If you're already using Guava, you can use [`Booleans.toArray()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Booleans.html#toArray(java.util.Collection)):

```
or(Booleans.toArray(listOfBooleans))
```

Comment: Seems like it should work, but, sadly, I don't know how to use  overload... yet :) And no, I don't use Guava, just plain Java 1.8

Comment: An overload is just a fancy name for a method in the same class with the same name but different parameters; just define it like any other method. But you don't need it to have the same name, nor have it in the same class: you just need this "helper method" somewhere.

Comment: I understood. Should work, can't check it now, but sounds awesome :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read an entire line as a string and then parse it:

```
System.out.println("Enter some booleans (true/false) separated by spaces: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = sc.nextLine();

Boolean[] booleans = 
    Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).map(Boolean::valueOf).toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's what I wrote.. I can't pass Boolean[] into or, because "Cannot resolve method 'or(java.lang.Boolean[]' "

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of boolean to the method. I wrote a quick example of parsing a boolean from a string, storing it in an array and passing it to your or method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean[] vals = new boolean[1];
    vals[0] = Boolean.parseBoolean("false"); 
}

public static boolean or(boolean... args) {
    return hasArgs & kiekFalse!=args.length ? true : false;
}
```

I would suggest to read the booleans line by line from the keyboard input and just pass then into an array or a list.
Hope it solves your problem.